# A question about a Theorem about MLE

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, inference

I have a question about a proof (about MLE) but let me  firstly give you appropriate context.

An estimator T is called maximum likelihood estimator of  $\theta$, if:
\begin{equation}L(T(\boldsymbol{x});\boldsymbol{x}) = max\space{} L(\theta ;\boldsymbol{x})   \end{equation}

Theorem

> if $\gamma = g(\theta)$ and $g$ is bijective, i.e $\theta = g^{-1}(\gamma)$, then $\hat{\theta}$ is a MLE for $\theta$ iff $g(\hat{\theta}) = \hat{\gamma}$
> is a MLE for $\gamma$

The proof:
The likelihood function is $L(\theta;\boldsymbol{x}) = p(\boldsymbol{x};\theta)$. since $g$ is bijective the likelihood function with respect to $\gamma$ is given by $\tilde{L}(\gamma;\boldsymbol{x})=p(\boldsymbol{x};g^{-1}(\gamma))$. Furthermore,we have

> $\tilde{L}( \hat{\gamma};\boldsymbol{x}) \geq \tilde{L}( \gamma;\boldsymbol{x})$ for all $\gamma$
>
> $\Leftrightarrow p(\boldsymbol{x};g^{-1}(\hat{\gamma})) \geq p(\boldsymbol{x};g^{-1}(\gamma))$ for all $\gamma$
>
> $\Leftrightarrow  p(\boldsymbol{x}:\hat{\theta}) \geq p(\boldsymbol{x};\theta)$ for all $\theta$
>
> $\Leftrightarrow L(\hat{\theta};\boldsymbol{x}) \geq L(\theta;\boldsymbol{x})$ for all $\theta$

The thing that is bothering me  about the proof is this statement:

> since $g$ is bijective the likelihood function with respect to $\gamma$ is given by $\tilde{L}(\gamma;\boldsymbol{x})=p(\boldsymbol{x};g^{-1}(\gamma))$

But in this case $\tilde{L}(\gamma ;\boldsymbol{x}) = p(\boldsymbol{x}:\theta )$ which is a function of $\theta$ but how can that be? I am missing something important...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $p$ is taken to be a function of $\theta$ and not $\gamma$.  So if we want to write the likelihood in terms of $p$ and the parameter $\gamma$, then we need to plug in the value for $\theta$ corresponding to $\gamma$, which is $g^{-1}(\gamma)$.

For instance, take a single observation $x$ from an exponential$(\lambda)$ distribution, where $\lambda$ is the *rate* parameter.  The likelihood function is then $L(\lambda) = \lambda e^{- \lambda x}$.  But the likelihood expressed in terms of the *mean* parameter $\mu = 1 / \lambda$ (so $g(t) = 1 / t$) is $\tilde{L}(\mu) = e^{- x / \mu} / \mu$, which is simply the original likelihood evaluated at $g^{-1}(\mu) = 1 / \mu$.